# Scikit-learn multi-output classifier using: GridSearchCV, Pipeline, OneVsRestClassifier, SGDClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I am attempting to build a multi-output model with GridSearchCV and Pipeline. The Pipeline is giving me trouble because standard classifier examples don't have the OneVsRestClassifier() wrapping the classifier. I'm using scikit-learn 0.18 and python 3.5

```
## Pipeline: Train and Predict
## SGD: support vector machine (SVM) with gradient descent
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

clf = Pipeline([
               ('vect', CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,3), max_df=0.50 ) ),
               ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer() ),
               ('clf', SGDClassifier(loss='modified_huber', penalty='elasticnet',
                                          alpha=1e-4, n_iter=5, random_state=42,
                                          shuffle=True, n_jobs=-1) ),
                ])

ovr_clf = OneVsRestClassifier(clf ) 

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
parameters = {'vect__ngram_range': [(1,1), (1,3)],
              'tfidf__norm': ('l1', 'l2', None),
              'estimator__loss': ('modified_huber', 'hinge',),
             }

gs_clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipeline, param_grid=parameters, 
                      scoring='f1_weighted', n_jobs=-1, verbose=1)
gs_clf = gs_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

But this yields the error:
....

> ValueError: Invalid parameter estimator for estimator
>   Pipeline(steps=[('vect', CountVectorizer(analyzer='word',
>   binary=False, decode_error='strict',
>           dtype=, encoding='utf-8', input='content',
>           lowercase=True, max_df=0.5, max_features=None, min_df=1,
>           ngram_range=(1, 3), preprocessor=None, stop_words=None,
>           strip...er_t=0.5, random_state=42, shuffle=True,
>          verbose=0, warm_start=False),
>             n_jobs=-1))]). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.

So what is the correct way to pass parameters to clf through the OneVsRestClassifier using param_grid and Pipeline? Do I need to separate the vectorizer and tdidf from the classifier in the Pipeline?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pass OneVsRestClassifier() as a step of pipeline itself and SGDClassifier as estimator of OneVsRestClassifier.
You can go like this.

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
               ('vect', CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,3), max_df=0.50 ) ),
               ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer() ),
               ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(SGDClassifier(loss='modified_huber', penalty='elasticnet',
                                          alpha=1e-4, n_iter=5, random_state=42,
                                          shuffle=True, n_jobs=-1) )),
                ])
```

Rest of the code can remain same. OneVsRestClassifier acts as a wrapper on other estimators.

Comment: That worked! (1) I moved the OneVsRestClassifier inside the pipeline to wrap SGDClassifier. (2) I added the prefix 'clf__' to the param_grid handling estimator parameters i.e. 'clf__estimator__penalty'.

Comment: getting "ValueError: multiclass-multioutput is not supported" for MultiOutputClassifier using as wrap and using f1_weighted     
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py", line 1250, in _check_set_wise_labels
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py", line 98, in _check_targets
    raise ValueError("{0} is not supported".format(y_type))
ValueError: multiclass-multioutput is not supported